# Unable to scrape some text out of a hidden container

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape a certain text located within class ***floorplan*** which is within `right-column` which again within `modal-body`. However, when I run my script, it gives blank output?

[link to that site](https://khovsecure.ml3ds-cloud.com/index.html?_ga=2.181197287.1174152084.1550480313-902396065.1550480313#/lotmap/43935)

Elements before click (values are null in `floorplan` and `swing` classes):

```
<div class="right-column">
    <div class="field" ng-show="selectedLot.Name !== ''">
        <div class="label">Home Design:</div>
        <div class="floorplan value ng-binding"></div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="field" ng-show="selectedLot.ShortDescription !== ''">
        <div class="label">Elevation:</div>
        <div class="swing value ng-binding"></div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="field" ng-show="selectedLot.Swing !== ''">
        <div class="label">Swing:</div>
        <div class="swing value ng-binding"></div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

After click (values are there now in `floorplan` and `swing` classes):

```
<div class="right-column">
    <div class="field" ng-show="selectedLot.Name !== ''">
        <div class="label">Home Design:</div>
        <div class="floorplan value ng-binding">Delaware</div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="field" ng-show="selectedLot.ShortDescription !== ''">
        <div class="label">Elevation:</div>
        <div class="swing value ng-binding">TRA</div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="field" ng-show="selectedLot.Swing !== ''">
        <div class="label">Swing:</div>
        <div class="swing value ng-binding">Garage Right</div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried so far with (`can't make my script click on that image to reveal the data I'm after`):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def collect_links(link):
    driver.get(link)
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"path#ip-loader-circle")))
    item = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".modal-body .right-column .floorplan")))
    print(item.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://khovsecure.ml3ds-cloud.com/index.html?_ga=2.181197287.1174152084.1550480313-902396065.1550480313#/lotmap/43935"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
    collect_links(url)
    driver.quit()
```

Expected output:

```
Delaware
```

This is how the information popped up in a box when a click is initiated on that map:

[image]

> ***How can I make a click on that map to scrape the desired text from the pop up container?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below give you all data in json format:

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    headers = {
        'fullurl': 'https://khovsecure.ml3ds-cloud.com/index.html?_ga=2.181197287.1174152084.1550480313-902396065.1550480313#/lotmap/43935',
    }
    response = requests.get('https://khovsecure.ml3ds-cloud.com/resources/data/CommunityData/khovsecure.ml3ds-cloud.com', headers=headers)
    print(response.json())
```

Comment: I get timeout exception error when i tried your suggested script. The elements are present only when a click is performed on the map. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU check my answer update. No need for selenium to get data, you can use requests to get all as json and then just parse it.

Comment: Yeah, it looks better @Sers. Where have you found this link? I tried getting the same link using chrome dev tool in it's `All` and `xhr` tab but I could not find the same? Can suggest me the way? Thanks.

Comment: In devtools go network tab and refresh the page, then you can find the link.